# MySQL 'ETIMEDOUT' error MacOS Monterey when attempting to connect to server

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, request-timed-out

I think I have exhausted all of my options for trying to get MySQL to connect to my express server. Scoured the Google machine, etc.. I am fairly new to MySQL, although I had to wipe out my computer recently and have since tried to get MySQL working to no avail.

I am able to connect to MySQL and create a db locally. However, when trying to connect to the server it looks like it will work, and then after about 10 seconds I am greeted with an `ETIMEDOUT` error. I'm guessing that this is a network error of some sort, I just can't seem to get to the bottom of it.

For what it's worth I am using the latest MacOS, Node v17.6.0, Server version: 8.0.28 Homebrew

I verified the correct port:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

The error message:

```
Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> quit
Bye
chriss-air:demo-db pesarcomputer$ npm start

> demo-db@1.0.0 start
> node server.js

Connected to the election database
Server running on port 3306
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/Users/pesarcomputer/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/my-sql/demo-db/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:189:17)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._notifyError (/Users/pesarcomputer/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/my-sql/demo-db/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:236:12)
    at Connection._handleFatalError (/Users/pesarcomputer/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/my-sql/demo-db/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:167:10)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (/Users/pesarcomputer/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/my-sql/demo-db/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:180:10)
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/Users/pesarcomputer/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/my-sql/demo-db/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:193:10)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}

Node.js v17.6.0
chriss-air:demo-db pesarcomputer$ lsof -i :3306
COMMAND    PID          USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld    3104 pesarcomputer   21u  IPv4 0xd408ceb9108e063      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)
mysqld    3104 pesarcomputer   36u  IPv4 0xd408ceb96cb4b43      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql->localhost:49631 (ESTABLISHED)
TablePlus 3143 pesarcomputer   20u  IPv4 0xd408ceb9109c013      0t0  TCP localhost:49631->localhost:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
chriss-air:demo-db pesarcomputer$
```

Here is my code:

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const express = require("express");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3306;
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection(
  {
    host: "localhost",
    port: "3306",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "election",
    // debug: true,
  },
  console.log("Connected to the election database")
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "Hello World",
  });
});

// app.use((req, res) => {
//   res.status(404).end();
// });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3306 is your DB Port. Change the other port (const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3306;) to something else, typically 3000 or 3001.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark! When I try 3000 | 3001 I get the following error: ECONREFUSED ::1:3306

Comment: Super weird but I seem to have fixed it by changing `host: 127.0.0.1` However I am confused as to why? I know that it runs on 127.0.0.1.. So I guess I would just need to figure out how to configure localhost to be 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Zoinks. That should be a system config issue. Hopefully the googles will be kinder to you with that error. Your code is fine with the change to 3001, as it works on my end.

Comment: I was able to get into the hosts using this command `sudo open -a TextEdit /etc/hosts` but it's saying that localhost is already 127.0.0.1...? This would mean that `host: localhost` should work... But it's not?

Answer (score 1):

This fixes the error:

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const express = require("express");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection(
  {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    port: "3306",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "election",
    // debug: true,
  },
  console.log("Connected to the election database")
);
```

However, I'd like to configure localhost to be 127.0.0.1 How would I do that?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but rather a question, you should include it in the question

Comment: After hours of trials, changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" fixed it for me